# does "never see your pockets empty anymore" make any sense?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

We were talking about money in our English class and I said this:

> learn programming and never see your pockets empty anymore

does it make any sense to you? is the sentence correct?

Comment: It may not be a standard expression, but it's perfectly acceptable English and makes its meaning clear.